# Calculate the Sum of the filtered GridView Bound field Column using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two `textboxes` and one `GridView` on a `ASP.net webpage`. One `textbox` filters the Bound field `Columns` of `GridView`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" class="tbox" style="width:330px" AutoPostBack="true" onkeypress="" runat="server"  onkeyup="Search_Gridview(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

**ASP.NET GridView**

```
<asp:GridView HorizontalAlign="Left" style="margin-top:5px;"  RowStyle-Wrap="false" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="#008269" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#eaeff3" HeaderStyle-Height="37px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" CellPadding="6"  ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" ShowFooter="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f1f4f7"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>                   
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesInvoiceID" HeaderText="Sales Invoice ID" SortExpression="SalesInvoiceID">
            <HeaderStyle Width="110px" />
            </asp:BoundField>                  
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="DateSold"  HeaderText="Date of Invoice" SortExpression="DateSold" ReadOnly="True">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name"  HeaderText="Customer Name" SortExpression="Name">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCNIC" HeaderText="Customer CNIC" SortExpression="CustomerCNIC">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile1" HeaderText="Mobile #" SortExpression="Mobile1">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModeOfPayment" HeaderText="Payment Mode" SortExpression="ModeOfPayment" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalBill" HeaderText="Total Bill" SortExpression="TotalBill">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="RemainingBill" HeaderText="Remaining Due Amount" SortExpression="RemainingBill" ReadOnly="True">
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>                         
    <HeaderStyle  BackColor="#FFFF99" ForeColor="#008269" Height="30px" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="GridHeading"></HeaderStyle>
    <RowStyle Wrap="False"></RowStyle>          
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to calculate the sum of filtered `column` (e.g `HeaderText="Remaining Due Amount"`) and show the result into 2nd `textbox` using `javascript`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" class="tbox"  style="width:200px;margin-right:10px;float:right;" runat="server" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript for Gridview Filteration**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search_Gridview(strKey) {
        var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var tblData = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
        var rowData;
        for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
            rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
            var styleDisplay = 'none';
            for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                    styleDisplay = '';
                else {
                    styleDisplay = 'none';
                    break;
                }
            }
            tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
        }
    }
</script>
```